# JSON - Unable to parse

Tags: json

I am unable to parse the following piece. 
Please let me know if you have any clue(s)

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
var s = '{"CCMP_11":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eFor all inputs received, automated sanity checks with the last cycle data are performed and QC of control totals are conducted.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CCMP_11","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":2.75,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"CCMP_20":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eAll client deliverable reports / files (interim and final) containing compliance sensitive data are clearly marked with requisite compliance circulation warning before sharing with the client.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CCMP_20","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":3.25,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"CCMP_21":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eAll system changes and QC results are reviewed by a senior team member. Review comments are incorporated and rerun test results are shared with the project manager and formal sign off is taken.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CCMP_21","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":3.75,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"IC_6":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eNo parallel tools (eg. Deconstructor tool) are used for QC and automated QCs are established for any deliverable\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"IC_6","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":3.25,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"IC_12":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eAll the Javelin-to-Javelin integrations are in place as a precursor to implementing Next Gen Sales Compensation (NGSC)\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"IC_12","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":2.75,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"CCMP_29":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eError-free runs are celebrated and team achievements are recognized at least once a quarter.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CCMP_29","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":3.66667,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"CCMP_18":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eResponsibilities are clearly defined and accountability is created within the team as to who will implement and who will check the compliance aspects.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CCMP_18","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Implemented, but not doing consistently","Answer":4,"OverallMean":3.5,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"CCMP_4":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eStandard reusable templates are created for deliverables and/or communication that are shared with the client on a regular basis:\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CCMP_4","CheckBoxListItems":"E-mail templates||||Minutes of Meeting||||Status Updates||||Adhoc/Change Request Form","CheckBoxListLabels":"1||||2||||3||||4","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"1,3","AnswerText":"Planning in progress","Answer":2,"OverallMean":3.6,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"IC_3":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eParameterization: All Ad-hoc Inputs to the system have a placeholder within the system and are handled through data inputs (e.g. consuming adjustment blocks for sales,  goal adjustment, payout adjustment, eligibility exceptions,   product weights, report metrics, plan parameters)\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp\u003eA list of all use cases that need system changes during or between operations is maintained by the project and is being worked with JPS team for building the same within the system.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"IC_3","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Planning in progress","Answer":2,"OverallMean":3.5,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"IC_8":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eThe Individual who runs operations does NOT have access to make system changes ( e.g. data structure change, business rule change, procedure change, report template change, etc.)\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"IC_8","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Planning in progress","Answer":2,"OverallMean":2.75,"SectionName":"Common Minimum Practices","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":-999},"CRM_4":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eAn internal ZS approval and a formal client sign-off on the scope of all change requests and the revised timelines (if any) is obtained, as per the ChaRM framework.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CRM_4","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":3.16667,"SectionName":"Change Request Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":3},"CRM_5":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003ePeer reviews are formally planned and conducted for all changes. All outcomes are documented and action items tracked until completion.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CRM_5","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Planning in progress","Answer":2,"OverallMean":3.33333,"SectionName":"Change Request Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":3},"CRM_1":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003e* All changes impacting the creation or change of business rules are documented in accordance with the Change Request Management (ChaRM) framework and have the following sections:\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp\u003e\u003col\u003e\u003cli\u003eChange description\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eImpacted deliverables\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eBusiness use cases and expected results\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eChange details for inputs, process and output sections along with assumptions\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eInput/output mockups indicating changes for all business cases\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eRisks, if any\u003c/li\u003e\u003cli\u003eCosts, if any\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ol\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp\u003eClear owner(s) are identified who will be accountable for tracking all requirement/business rule change decisions and documenting them properly.\u003c/p\u003e \u003cp\u003eClick here to understand ChaRM framework in detail.\u003cbr /\u003e\u003ca target=_blank href=\"https://zspace.zsassociates.com/docs/DOC-43529\"\u003ehttps://zspace.zsassociates.com/docs/DOC-43529\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CRM_1","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Planning in progress","Answer":2,"OverallMean":3.16667,"SectionName":"Change Request Management","IsChecked":true,"SectionId":3},"CRM_2":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eOnTrak/ client tool or Excel template is used by the project team and/or client to implement a structured review-approve process for:\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"\u003cp\u003eFollowing parameters should be added for each ticket - Complexity, Business impact, process impact, scope, ownerships, impact on deliverables, testing and functional design, timelines, business context.\u003c/p\u003e \u003cp\u003e\u003ca target=_blank href = \"https://zspace.zsassociates.com/docs/DOC-45596\"\u003eClick here\u003c/a\u003e to see the OnTrak guides on ZSpace.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionId":"CRM_2","CheckBoxListItems":"Observed defects, enhancements, issues, rework, Adhocs and operational items||||Changes of Business rules||||Change requests and operations related items (e.g. approvals, confirmations, Input notification, etc.)","CheckBoxListLabels":"1||||2||||3","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"2","AnswerText":"Implemented, but not doing consistently","Answer":4,"OverallMean":3.66667,"SectionName":"Change Request Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":3},"CRM_3":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eA comprehensive impact analysis of change requests is conducted using Data Flow Diagrams (DFDs) and documented. A template capturing the impact of all change requests and associated dependencies is maintained internally by the team.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp\u003ePlease refer to the ChaRM framework for the template:\u003cbr /\u003e\u003ca target=_blank href=\"https://zspace.zsassociates.com/docs/DOC-43529\"\u003ehttps://zspace.zsassociates.com/docs/DOC-43529\u003c/a\u003e\u003cp\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"CRM_3","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Implementation in progress","Answer":3,"OverallMean":3.83333,"SectionName":"Change Request Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":3},"PM_3":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003e* Cross-work stream trainings are planned and imparted to team members.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"PM_3","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":2.75,"SectionName":"People Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":6},"PM_5":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eAll the project team members are provided in the moment/immediate feedback by applying the COIN framework. The channels leveraged include email, informal/formal meeting or ZS COIN app.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"PM_5","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":3.33333,"SectionName":"People Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":6},"PM_7":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eThe EVOLVE program sheet is maintained for all team roles and is used for team reviews and role discussions with team members.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"PM_7","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Not considering","Answer":1,"OverallMean":3.33333,"SectionName":"People Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":6},"PM_4":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003e* Backup and succession planning is done periodically (at least each semester) and well documented. The team structure and upcoming resource needs are also reviewed as a part of the same.\u003c/p\u003e\u003cp\u003eClick on the link below to see sample documents on ZSpace\u003cbr /\u003e \u003ca target=_blank href=\"https://zspace.zsassociates.com/docs/DOC-45693\"\u003ehttps://zspace.zsassociates.com/docs/DOC-45693\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"PM_4","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Planning in progress","Answer":2,"OverallMean":4,"SectionName":"People Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":6},"PM_6":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eThe project Consultant/Manager has a formal one on one discussion with each team member at least once a quarter.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"PM_6","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Planning in progress","Answer":2,"OverallMean":3.66667,"SectionName":"People Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":6},"PM_8":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003eThe project manager sets specific short and long-term goals for each individual for each review period.\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"","QuestionId":"PM_8","CheckBoxListItems":"","CheckBoxListLabels":"","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"","AnswerText":"Planning in progress","Answer":2,"OverallMean":3,"SectionName":"People Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":6},"PM_2":{"QuestionText":"\u003cp\u003e* A training, transition \u0026 onboarding plan is setup for the project which includes a list of courses that each team member should take and is consistently followed for all project onboardings.\u003cp\u003e\u003c/p\u003eThe training, transition and onboarding plans should also cover:\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionPrefix":"","QuestionSuffix":"\u003cp\u003eClick on the link below to see sample documents on ZSpace \u003cbr /\u003e\u003ca target=_blank href=\"https://zspace.zsassociates.com/docs/DOC-45692\"\u003ehttps://zspace.zsassociates.com/docs/DOC-45692\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/p\u003e","QuestionId":"PM_2","CheckBoxListItems":"Client Business context and team structure||||Business rules||||Project SOW and noteworthy Work orders/Change requests||||Process Visio Diagrams for system overview and detailed sections||||Project Calendar||||SLA details||||System Access setup||||System inputs||||System setup including Javelin Suite||||Deliverables||||Tools","CheckBoxListLabels":"1||||2||||3||||4||||5||||6||||7||||8||||9||||10||||11","CheckBoxes":null,"CheckBoxResponseCodes":"1,2","AnswerText":"Implementation in progress","Answer":3,"OverallMean":3.5,"SectionName":"People Management","IsChecked":false,"SectionId":6}}';
var v = JSON.parse(s);
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<body>
TESTING JSON
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Some of the string values in the json have unescaped double quotes.

Comment: What is the source of 's'?

Answer (score 0):

String should be supported by JSON, You have unwanted characters in your string, You must remove those character from string.

Example :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
var s = '{"CCMP_11":{"hello":"hai"}}'; // Correct string format for JSON
var v = JSON.parse(s);
console.log(v);
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<body>
TESTING JSON
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the inputs but I found a way to solve this

```
<JsonObj> = Json(<strForJson>.Replace("/\u0000/g", ""), "string", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```